# How to verify ODBC version is the one on the odbc.ini file?

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, ubuntu, odbc

I have a requirement to configure shell to install specified version of ODBC.

The app that I'm configuring is an Angular app that uses janusgraph for storing data it is hosted on docker locally.

I updated the odbc.ini file, added the designed version. ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I also updated the install-odbc.sh file and added the version details.

```
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17=-17.8.so.1.1
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
# apt-show-versions msodbcsql17
msodbcsql17:amd64/bionic 17.8.1.1-1 uptodate
```

Then I deleted the app and installed it again from scratch, everything was successful and my app is backup and running on my local setup on docker.

The only challenge I have is how do I verify that indeed the ODBC version is the one on the odbc.ini file?

ODBC.ini

```
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
Description     = MSSQL Server
Trace           = Yes
Server          = 10.0.0.0
Database        = IT_D
Port            = 1433
TDS_Version     = 7.4
QuotedId        = YES
AnsiNPW         = YES
Encrypt         = YES
TrustServerCertificate = YES
#VarMaxAsLong=YES

[Default]
Driver          = /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
```

Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /root/importer

RUN apt-get -y update
# RUN apt-get -y install wget
# RUN wget https://rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
# Wget not properly resolved by Jenkins, using local file as fallback
COPY ./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem ./

COPY ./install-odbc.sh ./
RUN apt-get -y install gnupg2
RUN apt-get -y install dos2unix
RUN dos2unix ./install-odbc.sh

# Make sure the microsoft ODBC repository can be added as signed source
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y curl apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
# RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --keyserver-options http-proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} --recv-keys xxxxxx1229xx

RUN bash ./install-odbc.sh

# Node.js v14
RUN apt-get install -y git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev python
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get clean
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v

# Oracle installation
ENV ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR 19.6
ENV ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION 19.6.0.0.0
ENV ORACLE /usr/local/oracle
ENV ORACLE_HOME $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH $C_INCLUDE_PATH:$ORACLE/include/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 \
        curl rpm2cpio cpio \
    && mkdir $ORACLE && TMP_DIR="$(mktemp -d)" && cd "$TMP_DIR" \
    && curl -L https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19600/oracle-instantclient${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR}-basic-${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION}-1.x86_64.rpm -o basic.rpm \
    && rpm2cpio basic.rpm | cpio -i -d -v && cp -r usr/* $ORACLE && rm -rf ./* \
    && ln -s libclntsh.so.${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR} $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR \
    && ln -s libocci.so.${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR} $ORACLE/lib/oracle/$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR/client64/lib/libocci.so.$ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_MAJOR \
    && echo "$ORACLE_HOME/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf && chmod o+r /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf && ldconfig \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove curl rpm2cpio cpio

COPY ./dist/. ./
COPY ./package*.json ./
COPY ./tsconfig.json ./

# RUN npm install node-pre-gyp
RUN npm install

RUN node -v

COPY ./odbc.ini /etc/
RUN dos2unix /etc/odbc.ini
RUN cp /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/* /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql
RUN ls /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64

COPY ./sqlnet.ora $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
RUN dos2unix $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

# CMD bash -c "npm run start:watch"
CMD bash -c "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./app.js"
```

I tried to check docker logs but I couldn't file anything that indicates that the ODBC has been updated.

Can you please assist me with the steps to check the ODBC version used by my app.

Thanks in advance

Sivuyile

Comment: Thanks a lot gurus, I found a way to check by using a bash command:   ls /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/